# Нужна ли запятая после слова "удивлятся"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Неподготовленный зритель сильно удивляется, прогуливаясь в его окрестностях, потому что совершенно не понятно, откуда же должна падать такая огромная масса воды?"

Answer (score 3):

Да, конечно, нужна. Ведь дальше идёт деепричастный оборот "прогуливаясь в окрестностях". Кстати, слово  "непонятно" в данном случае лучше написать слитно.  Наречие меры и степени "совершенно" подчеркивает утверждение, а не отрицание.